# Javascript string replace of dots (.) within filenames

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to parse and amend some html (as a string) using javascript and in this html, there are references (like img src or css backgrounds) to filenames which contain full stops/periods/dots/.

e.g.

```
<img src="../images/filename.01.png"> <img src="../images/filename.02.png">
<div style="background:url(../images/file.name.with.more.dots.gif)">
```

I've tried, struggled and failed to come up with a neat regex to allow me to parse this string and spit it back out without the dots in those filenames, e.g.

```
<img src="../images/filename01.png"/> <img src="../images/filename02.png"/>
<div style="background:url(../images/filenamewithmoredots.gif)">
```

I only want to affect the image filenames, and obviously I want to leave the filetype alone.

A regex like:

```
/(.*)(?=(.gif|.png|.jpg|.jpeg))
```

allows me to match the main part of the filename and the extension seperately, but it also matches across the whole of the string, not just within the one filename I want.

I have no control over the incoming html, I'm just consuming it.

Help me please overflowers, you're my only hope!

Comment: Should there be **no** dots in your 2nd example code block?

Comment: There aren't. `filename.01.png` becomes `filename01.png`

Comment: Ah gotcha I thought you meand the .. dir path

Comment: Parsing HTML with a regexp is almost always a mistake. If you know in advance which attributes to allow for, you *might* get away with it; but your "url(.." introduces more problems. Don't do it: use an HTML or Dom parser.

Comment: Are you using jQuery, or do you have access to it? That would simplify this (or at least, it would simplify the technique I'd use).

Comment: Yeah, I'm also using jQuery and am liking the idea of crawling the DOM, will give that a go.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that this is not a problem suitable for regular expression, much less one neat expression.

But I trust that you are not here to hear that. So, in case you want to keep the input as string...

```
var src, result = '<img src="../images/filename.01.png"> <img src="../images/filename.02.png"><div style="background:url(../images/file.name.with.more.dots.gif)">';
do {
  src = result;  
  result = src.replace( /((?:url(\()|href=|src=)['"]?(?:[^'"\/]*\/)*[^'"\/]*)\.(?=[^\.'")]*\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g)['")>}\s])/g, '$1' );
} while (result != src)
```

Basically it keeps removing the second last dot of images url's filenames until there are none.  Here is a breakdown of the expression in case you need to modify it.  Tread lightly:

- `(` start main capturing group since js regx has no lookbehind.

  - `(?:url(\()|href=|src=)['"]?` Start of an url. it would be safer to force url() to be properly quoted so that we can use back reference, but unfortunately your given example is not.
  - `(?:[^'"\/]*\/)*` Folder part of the url.
  - `[^'"\/]*` Part of the file name that comes before second last dot.
- `)` close main group.
- `\.` This is the second last dot we want to get rid of.
- `(?=` Look behind.

  - `[^\.'")]*` Part of the file name that goes between second last dot and last dot.
  - `\.(?:gif|png|jpe?g)` Make sure the url ends in image extension.
  - `['")>}\s]` Closing the url, which can be a quote, ')', '>', '}', or spaces. Should user back reference here if possible. (Was `['"]?\b` when first answered)
- `)` End of look behind.

Comment: Man, that regex is awesome!  I'm actually going to try that out, just to witness the beauty :)

Comment: Hehe. I love regx. Really. But remember that when you use regular expression to solve a problem, you get two problems - just changed the url closing part a bit; the original one wouldn't recognise patterns like ('a.b.gif').

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the DOM instead of regular expressions. One way is to create fake elements.

```
var fake = document.createElement('div');
fake.innerHTML = incomingHTML: // Not really part of JS standard but all the 'main' browsers support it
var background = fake.childNodes[0].style.background;
// Now use a regex if need be: /url\(\"?(.*)\"?\)/

// If img is at childNodes[1]
var url = fake.childNodes[1].src;
```

With jQuery this is far easier:

```
 $(incomingHTML).find('img').each(function() { $(this).attr('src'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the greedy match in `.*`. Maybe better try something like this

```
([^\/]*)(?=(.gif|.png|.jpg|.jpeg))
```

`[^\/]` is a character class that matches every character but slashes

another point is, you need to escape the `.` to match it literally

```
([^\/]*)(?=\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `.` means "any character".

Escape it:

```
/(.*)(?=(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg))
```